# Undefined index Doctrine error whe try to find record in DB

Tags: symfony, doctrine, find

I try to get row from DB but this code:

```
$company = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeCompanyBundle:Company')->find($company_id);
```

returns this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: company in /var/www/ontheway/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2714
```

Here is my Company entity on github:
[github](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/c78ec15c6f7e2e4f02a2)

Comment: Please update the question with your `Company` class...

Comment: I added link to gists, where you can see all my enttity

Comment: Can you show your User and Certificate entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Vputi\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="company", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Certificate", mappedBy="company", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $certificates;
```

You have both these:

```
targetEntity="\Vputi\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="company"
targetEntity="Certificate", mappedBy="company"
```

I would suspect that either `User` or `Certificate` entities **do not** have the `company` field. Do they?